# Difference between Date(dateString) and new Date(dateString)

Tags: javascript, date

I have some code that tries to parse a date string.

When I do `alert(Date("2010-08-17 12:09:36"));`
It properly parses the date and everything works fine but I can't call the methods associated with `Date`, like `getMonth()`.

When I try:

```
var temp = new Date("2010-08-17 12:09:36");
alert(temp);
```

I get an "invalid date" error.

Any ideas on how to parse "2010-08-17 12:09:36" with new Date()?

Comment: does alert(Date("2010-08-17 12:09:36").getMonth()); work?

I just pasted 
var temp = new Date("2010-08-17 12:09:36");
alert(temp);
in an HTML page and it worked fine.

Comment: Use new Date("2010-08-17T12:09:36") or new Date("2010-08-17T12:09:36Z") for UTC time.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Date()**

With this you call a function called `Date()`. It doesn't accept any arguments and returns a string representing the current date and time.

**new Date()**

With this you're creating a new instance of Date.

You can use only the following constructors:

```
new Date() // current date and time
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

So, use `2010-08-17 12:09:36` as parameter to constructor is not allowed.

See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp).

---

EDIT: `new Date(dateString)` uses one of these formats:

- "October 13, 1975 11:13:00"
- "October 13, 1975 11:13"
- "October 13, 1975"

Comment: Is there no other way to process the string without creating my own date parser?

Comment: I don't know how do this using native js. But you can use a external parser, like datejs (http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: Also in chrome and firefox new Date() works different. For example "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" is suitable for chrome but not for firefox.

Comment: *"It accepts date in format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss""* Maybe this was true 4 years ago, but no anymore today. `Date('2014-05-01 00:00:00')` simply returns the *current* date/time, in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @FelixKling, you forgot to call Date with the 'new' keyword.  new Date('2014-05-01 00:00:00') does give you the correct May 1st date.

Comment: @Jack: You are right, it works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. However, I was *specifically* referring to `Date`, without `new`. If you have a look at the answer again, it claims that `Date()` (without `new`) accepts a date string in that format, but it doesn't.

Comment: Oh, seems you are correct about FireFox.  I guess that's understandable since that format is non-standard.  Use a 'T' to designate the time (and optionally 'Z' for UTC time): "2014-05-01T00:00:00Z".

I don't think commenter intended to imply that the date constructor should be called without new when specifying a dateString.

Comment: Also note that you can use other formats. According to MDN...

`String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: This answer is quite out of date now. When called as a function, [*Date*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-value) accepts strings, numbers and objects. Also, it should never be passed a string (other than perhaps the [*format specified in ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format)) as the results are almost entirely implementation dependent (which was more so in 2010 with ECMA-262 ed 3 than now with ECMAScript 2015).

Comment: While some implementations may accept that format, it is not required to be supported by ECMA-262 up to ed 6 at least. Far better to use a 2 line parsing function.

Answer (score 39):

The following format works in *all* browsers:

```
new Date("2010/08/17 12:09:36");
```

So, to make a `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` formatted date string fully browser compatible you would have to replace dashes with slashes:

```
var dateString = "2010-08-17 12:09:36";
new Date(dateString.replace(/-/g, "/"));
```

Comment: +1 : worked for me in IE5-11 and seems the simplest solution when converting an ISO-8601 style string date.

Comment: No, don't do that. Far better to implement a 2 line function to manually parse the string (or use a library, but not really necessary). The language specification does note require browsers to parse **any** string other than ISO 8601 format, and some don't support that either.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is the fact (if I recall from the ECMA documentation) is that `Date("xx")` does not create (in a sense) a new date object (in fact it is equivalent to calling (`new Date("xx").toString()`). While `new Date("xx")` will actually create a new date object.

For More Information:

Look at 15.9.2 of http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but by far the easier solution is to just use

```
var temp = new Date("2010-08-17T12:09:36");
```

Comment: This fails in Safari.

Comment: Just because it fails in Safari doesn't mean it isn't a correct use of JavaScript. I don't have Safari to test this either, but I don't know why something this ubiquitous would work in some browsers and not in others. In any event it definitely isn't deserving of a down vote.

Comment: @TheComposer—welcome to the world of browser scripting. Until ES5, there was **no** string that browsers were required to parse by the standard. Some of those browsers are still in use. It is a certainty that at any point in time there are browsers in use that don't fully support the most recent standard (or even one a few years old), so you must program for the lowest common denominator of what browsers support, not strictly what the current specification states.

Comment: Parsing strings with the Date constructor is very widely recommended against, for good reasons (such as "browser X doesn't support that format").

Comment: The OP never even mentions that he is programming in a browser. It works in Node, multiple mainstream browsers, and is used in examples in both W3 and Mozilla Documentation. So, I stand by my claim that while knowing that it fails in this or that is a good piece of information to note, it does properly answer the question within reasonable assumptions and is still not deserving of a down vote.

Comment: Please share more details. What did you change and why? Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: This is a 9 year old answer... Especially when the edit would just be saying because the format op was using wasn't correct because it was missing the single character difference. If a user can't process that difference, it is unlikely that an overly explained version of this answer will help them either.

Answer (score 3):

Correct ways to use Date : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Also, the following piece of code shows how, with a single definition of the function "Animal", it can be a) called directly and b) instantiated by treating it as a constructor function

```
function Animal(){
    this.abc = 1;
    return 1234; 
}

var x = new Animal();
var y = Animal();

console.log(x); //prints object containing property abc set to value 1
console.log(y); // prints 1234
```

Answer (score 3):

> Any ideas on how to parse "2010-08-17 12:09:36" with new Date()?

Until ES5, there was no string format that browsers were required to support, though there are a number that are widely supported. However browser support is unreliable an inconsistent, e.g. some will allow out of bounds values and others wont, some support certain formats and others don't, etc.

ES5 introduced support for some ISO 8601 formats, however the OP is not compliant with ISO 8601 and not all browsers in use support it anyway.

The only reliable way is to use a small parsing function. The following parses the format in the OP and also validates the values.

```js
/* Parse date string in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
** If string contains out of bounds values, an invalid date is returned
** 
** @param {string} s - string to parse, e.g. "2010-08-17 12:09:36"
**                     treated as "local" date and time
** @returns {Date}   - Date instance created from parsed string
*/
function parseDateString(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1] && d.getHours() == b[3] &&
         d.getMinutes() == b[4]? d : new Date(NaN);
}
  
document.write(
  parseDateString('2010-08-17 12:09:36') + '<br>' +  // Valid values
  parseDateString('2010-08-45 12:09:36')             // Out of bounds date
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue using an API call which responded in ISO 8601 format. 
Working in Chrome this worked:
 `

```
// date variable from an api all in ISO 8601 format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
  var date = oDate['events']['event'][0]['start_time'];
  var eventDate = new Date();
  var outputDate = eventDate.toDateString();
```

`

but this didn't work with firefox.

Above answer helped me format it correctly for firefox:

```
 // date variable from an api all in ISO 8601 format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
 var date = oDate['events']['event'][0]['start_time'];
 var eventDate = new Date(date.replace(/-/g,"/");
 var outputDate = eventDate.toDateString();
```

Comment: No, don't pass strings to the Date constructor. Parsing of an ISO 8601 date requires 2 lines of code, do that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create single `Date` object and update it using the static function `Date.now()` :

```
<!doctype html>
<html> <head></head>
<body>

<h1 id="datetime"></h1>

<script>
    elem_datetime = document.getElementById('datetime');
    var date = new Date();
    function sometimer()
    {
        setTimeout(sometimer, 1*1000); // wait 1 second and call again
        date.setTime(Date.now());
        elem_datetime.innerHTML = date.toDateString() + ' ' + date.toLocaleTimeString();
    }
    sometimer();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting an "invalid date" error.
Rather, the value of temp is "Invalid Date".

Is your date string in a valid format?
If you're using Firefox, check [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

In Firefox javascript console:

```
>>> Date.parse("2010-08-17 12:09:36");
NaN
>>> Date.parse("Aug 9, 1995")
807944400000
```

I would try a different date string format.

Zebi, are you using Internet Explorer?

Comment: There should be a 'T' instead of the whitespace

Answer (score -2):

I recently ran into this as well and this was a helpful post.  I took the above Topera a step further and this works for me in both chrome and firefox:

```
var temp = new Date(  Date("2010-08-17 12:09:36")   );
alert(temp);
```

the internal call to `Date()` returns a string that  `new Date()` can parse.

Comment: What is the use of two `Date()` here when you can directly feed the string in the `Date` constructor.

Comment: @friesrf Your answer is entirely wrong. Calling Date("2010-08-17 12:09:36") will always return the value of calling Date() without any parameters. So with above code snippet, you'll never get the parsed date object of malformed date string, instead a new date object that is equivalent to now.

Code doesn't produce an error never means it is functionally correct.