# How to treat json date as a date instead of string?

Tags: php, json

I am creating a json array with dates in there.

```
$result[] = array('startDate' => date("D M j G:i:s T Y"),
                            'endDate' => date("D M j G:i:s T Y"),
                            'title' => $event->title,
                            'description'=>$event->summary,
                            'priority'=>2);
```

The result i get is:

```
 {
startDate: "Wed Nov 21 0:55:44 UTC 2012",
endDate: "Wed Nov 21 0:55:44 UTC 2012",
title: "title",
description: "desc",
priority: 2
}
```

But i dont want the date to be quoted as string, what i need is this:

```
 {
startDate: Wed Nov 21 0:55:44 UTC 2012,
endDate: Wed Nov 21 0:55:44 UTC 2012,
title: "title",
description: "desc",
priority: 2
}
```

So is there a way that the date to not be treated as a string?

Comment: How are you generating the JSON string from the array?

Comment: i use the json_encode function

Comment: Isn't the point of quoting strings to ensure the JSON is well formed? For instance if the string is not quoted and you happen to have a comma in it JSON will be interpreted as ending that value there. and starting a new one, thus breaking the code. I don't see why you need it unquoted. Can you elaborate on your reasons?

Comment: i am using this library http://www.dpereyra.com/scripts/dp_calendar/demo/events.html
and the date required shouldnt be quoted. The challenge here is that i have to dynamically fill the json from php

Comment: There are no date values in [JSON](http://json.org/). What you want is not JSON. Your question does not make sense.

Comment: check my previous comment, is there a way to handle this, because as i realized the quoted string is the problem

Comment: Please learn about JSON before you use it. PHP generates a JSON string literal here where, if you evaluate it client-side, such as with `JSON.parse(…)`, the string value itself will not be quoted.

Comment: I had a quick look at the link you provided. The calendar is a JQuery  application and I can't find any references to JSON at all (in the documentation).  

However, even if you quote the JSON data (as cryptic states), the quotes are a part of the JSON "protocol" and stripped away when you read the JSON.

Answer (score 4):

There is no DATE value in JSON.  The only allowable "value" constructs in JSON are:

- Objects
- Arrays
- Double-quoted strings
- Numbers (integer or float)
- Boolean (`true` or `false` without quotes)
- `null`

So what you are asking for is not JSON format. You would need to build your own JSON-like serializer, or modify the string after `json_encode` is performed to remove the double quotes.

Or, you can just leave the JSON as it is, and use javascript to parse the string into a javascript `Date` object, which is what appears to be the intended input to that library.

See this post about how to parse strings into Date objects in javascript.

[Difference between Date(dateString) and new Date(dateString)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505693/difference-between-datedatestring-and-new-datedatestring)

Note: you will likely need to change your date format as what you have is not one of the typically accepted javascript `dateString` formats.