# Date(value) and new Date(value)

Tags: javascript, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Date(dateString) and new Date(dateString)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505693/difference-between-datedatestring-and-new-datedatestring)

What is the difference between

```
Date(1356567322705)
"Thu Dec 27 2012 03:13:37 GMT+0300 (Kaliningrad Standard Time)"
```

and

```
new Date(1356567322705)
Thu Dec 27 2012 03:15:22 GMT+0300 (Kaliningrad Standard Time)
```

and why there is a gap of about 2 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**: Note that JavaScript `Date` objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript `Date` as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the `new` operator) will return a string rather than a `Date` object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript `Date` objects have no literal syntax.

-- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: +1 for using the documentation.

Comment: The real documentation is [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9)