# Convert string to object

Tags: javascript, rest, angular, typescript

I'M making an angular2 application and right now i'm trying to parse a string into a object. Basically what is happening is I'm passing back a string, and i want to convert it into a unique object called IDate. 
I get a string in this format "2017-02-27T00:00:00", but i want it as IDate(). So what i have done so far is created a IDate class, that takes a string and converts it to a date. I created a Mock class to map the response to an object. However, when i print the object, i see the value stays a string. Anyone know how to achieve what I'm talking about? I'm basically trying to map the string to an object when i map the response from the controller. I could do this in an operation like, `resposne.map(r.time => new Date(r.time));`  But i rather have it mapped in the response, because i call this controllers in other places and i dont want to repeat the process on separate pages. Can this be done?

Controller

```
        return Json(new { Number = 1, Time= "2017-02-27T00:00:00" });
```

Client

```
class IDate {
    value: Date; 
    contructor(value) {
        this.value = new Date(value); 
    }
}
class Mock {
    number: number;
    time: IDate;
}
mock: Mock = null; 

 this.service.get()
            .subscribe(
            response => {
                console.log("Test response");
                this.mock = response;
                console.log(this.mock);
            },
```

Console

```
Object
  number:1
  time:"2017-02-27T00:00:00"
  __proto__:Object
```

Comment: That works if i passed an object in string format, im trying to pass a string and convert it into an object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Date(dateString) and new Date(dateString)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505693/difference-between-datedatestring-and-new-datedatestring)

Comment: @ScottMarcus Not what im trying to do, please read the question again and let me know if its not clear.

Comment: Looks like `constructor` is spelled wrong in your IDate class, not sure that's the issue though

Comment: Maybe i should change this question to how to return date types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are getting a JSON string from your REST API. If this holds true for your case, you may use a [`reviver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter). Here is a simplistic approach to use the `reviver`:

```
JSON.parse(jsonString, function (key, value) {
    if (key === "time")
        return new Date(value);
    return value;
})
```

Here is the link to a running fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sayan751/Lzb8u638/.

---

**Updated based on OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43145013/convert-string-to-object/43162550#comment73457919_43162550)**

Converting a generic object to an instance of a specific class is not very straight forward. Note that `this.mock = response;` does not covert `response` to an instance of `Mock` class (refer the new fiddle link).

You may use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), but it might not work with type conversion.

Also I think in your case, the schema of the json object `{Number:number, Time:string}` received in your JavaScript code does not match with the schema of `Mock`:`{number:number, time:{value:Date}}`.

In this case, it would be best (as per my opinion) to write a custom converter for `Mock`. One simplistic approach can be as below. For detailed code, refer the new fiddle link.

```
class Mock {
    number: number;
    time: IDate;

    public static create(obj):Mock{
        let retVal = new Mock();
      retVal.number=obj.number;

      if(typeof obj.time === "string")
        retVal.time = new Date(obj.time); //better to use moment in this case, if possible
      else if(obj.time instanceof Date)
        retVal.time = obj.time;

      return retVal;
    }
}

var jsonObj = { number: 1, time: "2017-02-27T00:00:00" };

var obj = Mock.create(jsonObj);
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sayan751/mxoqqc5a/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting a JSON object and it gets mapped to Mock class vai typescript, i would like the string data to be a date, but for some reason its not getting mapped to one.

Comment: I'm not instantiating the object, I'm trying to change the the value when it gets mapped, but i see you are saying that impossible.