# how to convert current date to YYYY-MM-DD format with angular 2

Tags: angular, date, typescript

i use this line to get the current date

```
public current_date=new Date();
```

and i have got this result:

```
Wed Apr 26 2017 10:38:12 GMT+0100 (Afr. centrale Ouest)
```

how can i transform that to this format

> YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 71):

For Angular 5

**app.module.ts**

```
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
.
.
.
providers: [DatePipe]
```

**demo.component.ts**

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
.
.
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

ngOnInit() {
   var date = new Date();
   console.log(this.datePipe.transform(date,"yyyy-MM-dd")); //output : 2018-02-13
}
```

more information [angular/datePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: I get this error: ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "de-DE".' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Answer (score 59):

Example as per doc

```
@Component({
  selector: 'date-pipe',
  template: `<div>
    <p>Today is {{today | date}}</p>
    <p>Or if you prefer, {{today | date:'fullDate'}}</p>
    <p>The time is {{today | date:'jmZ'}}</p>
  </div>`
})
export class DatePipeComponent {
  today: number = Date.now();
}
```

Template

```
{{ dateObj | date }}               // output is 'Jun 15, 2015'
{{ dateObj | date:'medium' }}      // output is 'Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'shortTime' }}   // output is '9:43 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'mmss' }}        // output is '43:11'
{{dateObj  | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} // 15/06/2015
```

To Use in your component.

```
@Injectable()
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
class MyService {

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    this.datePipe.transform(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); //whatever format you need. 
  }
}
```

In your app.module.ts

```
providers: [DatePipe,...]
```

all you have to do is use this service now.

Comment: Where was the OP expected output?

Comment: @RameshRajendran : Updated

Answer (score 12):

Try this below code it is also works well in angular 2

```
<span>{{current_date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>
```

Comment: actually i need it for a futur date comparaison in component

Comment: this `date: 'yyyy/MM/dd'`  is an common filter way to formatting date using angular

and you can create an constant to declare the format of `'yyyy/MM/dd'` and call the constant to your component

Comment: could you please give me same exemple how to pass current date from template to component after formatting

Comment: just use `new Date(this.current_date.replace(/-/g, "/"));` or more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505693/difference-between-datedatestring-and-new-datedatestring

Answer (score 6):

Here is a very nice and compact way to do this, you can also change this function as your case needs:

**result: 03.11.2017**

```
//get date now function
    getNowDate() {
    //return string
    var returnDate = "";
    //get datetime now
    var today = new Date();
    //split
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //because January is 0! 
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    //Interpolation date
    if (dd < 10) {
        returnDate += `0${dd}.`;
    } else {
        returnDate += `${dd}.`;
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
        returnDate += `0${mm}.`;
    } else {
        returnDate += `${mm}.`;
    }
    returnDate += yyyy;
    return returnDate;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Add the template and give date pipe, you need to use escape characters for the format of the date. You can give any format as you want like 'MM-yyyy-dd' etc.

```
template: '{{ current_date | date: \'yyyy-MM-dd\' }}',
```

Answer (score 4):

You can import

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
```

The standard format of the method.

```
formatDate(value: string | number | Date, format: string, locale: string, timezone?: string)
```

So here, all you have to do is pass your "current_date" in the method as value, then format (in your case "YYYY-MM-DD") and then locale, timezone is optional.

e.g.

```
formatDate(current_date,'yyyy-MM-dd',"en-US");
```

You will get your desired output.

For more reference, you can look into
[Angular-formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)

Comment: This works perfect, but to display it right it should be formatDate(current_date,'yyyy-MM-dd',"en-US") otherwise it shows January as 0, February as 1, March as 2, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Solution in ES6/TypeScript:

```js
let d = new Date;
console.log(d, [`${d.getFullYear()}`, `0${d.getMonth()}`.substr(-2), `0${d.getDate()}`.substr(-2)].join("-"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check date if valid "`date instanceof Date`" so you can convert as your format otherwise return same as
*Note:- We can use `new Date()` instead of `moments`

```
    convertIntoDate(value: string) {
     const date = new Date(value);
     if (date instanceof Date) {
       return moment(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
     } else {
       return value;
     }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).