# Convert TimeZone Time string correctly into Local Time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, timezone, momentjs

I am trying to convert a time string returned from our backend system but I am unable to get the correct local time.

Time string returned from backend: `"2020-08-28T07:00:00.000Z"`

Expected local time needed: `Aug 28, 2020 12:00 AM`

I tried:

1. converting it with `Moment.js` Failed:

   ```
       moment(backendTime).format(
        "MMM D,YYYY h:mm a"
     )
   ```

   Somehow I got "Jan 1st 20 12:00 AM", I don't understand it at all
2. converting it by casting to `Date` Failed as well:

```
  Date("2020-08-28T07:00:00.000Z")
```

Ended up getting: " Mon Sep 21 2020 00:07:29 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) "

I am running out of ideas right now, I feel it shouldn't be this difficult but just cannot get it.

Comment: which timezone are you in ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I am in Pacific Time,  is the timezone the cause of not getting it translated to the correct time ?

Comment: you can change date format by using this also: - console.log(format(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd kk:mm:ss'))

Answer (score 0):

The format you are getting is exactly what you have requested.

To get the output you desire using moment.js you need to use the following format:

```
moment(backendTime).format("MMM DD, YYYY hh:mm A");
```

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/oz6mx3nh/

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS you can use the [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) to format your dates based on a timezone. All the options for `DateTimeFormat` are [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).

The different options for the locale (`en-US`) is [listed here](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/language_tags.php)

Here is a [full list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) of all the time zones.

See bottom snippet for the output of each locale (in the provided list)

```js
const date = new Date("2020-08-28T07:00:00.000Z");

const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
  "en-US",
  {
    month: "short",
    day: "2-digit",
    year: "numeric",
    hour: "2-digit",
    hour12: true,
    minute: "2-digit",
    timeZone: "America/New_York",
  }
).format(date)

console.log(format);
```

A list of outputs from every locale:

```js
const date = new Date("2020-08-28T07:00:00.000Z");

const locales = ["ar-SA", "bn-BD", "bn-IN", "cs-CZ", "da-DK", "de-AT", "de-CH", "de-DE", "el-GR", "en-AU", "en-CA", "en-GB", "en-IE", "en-IN", "en-NZ", "en-US", "en-ZA", "es-AR", "es-CL", "es-CO", "es-ES", "es-MX", "es-US", "fi-FI", "fr-BE", "fr-CA", "fr-CH", "fr-FR", "he-IL", "hi-IN", "hu-HU", "id-ID", "it-CH", "it-IT", "jp-JP", "ko-KR", "nl-BE", "nl-NL", "no-NO", "pl-PL", "pt-BR", "pt-PT", "ro-RO", "ru-RU", "sk-SK", "sv-SE", "ta-IN", "ta-LK", "th-TH", "tr-TR", "zh-CN", "zh-HK", "zh-TW"];

const formatDate = (locale, date) => new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
  locale,
  {
    month: "short",
    day: "2-digit",
    year: "numeric",
    hour: "2-digit",
    hour12: true,
    minute: "2-digit",
    timeZone: "America/New_York",
  }
).format(date);

// Loop over each locale
for(const locale of locales) {
  const formatted = formatDate(locale, date);
  
  console.log(`${locale}: ${formatted}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Assuming your computer is set for Pacific time, then:

  ```
  moment("2020-08-28T07:00:00.000Z").format("MMM D, YYYY h:mm a")
  //=> "Aug 28, 2020 12:00 am"
  ```

  That will indeed return the value you expected.  You said you got `"Jan 1st 20 12:00 AM"`, but that is not possible, as neither the values nor the format matches.
- When you tried the `Date` object, you got the result you did because you omitted the `new` keyword ([see this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3505796/634824)).  It should instead be:

  ```
  new Date("2020-08-28T07:00:00.000Z")
  ```

  Keep in mind that this produces a `Date` object.  If you log that object directly, the result is implementation specific.  It may vary across browsers.  Instead, you should call a function such as `toString` or `toLocaleString` from it.
- If this is a new project, you should probably avoid using Moment.  Please read https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/