# Set timezone in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

my js file looks like below

```
var today = Date();
console.log(today); // Thu Aug 04 2022 15:28:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)


var today = new Date();
console.log(today); // 2022-08-04T09:58:52.640Z
```

I have set the local timezone in my centos to Asia/Calcutta and its `Date()` function is displaying correctly as `Aug 04 2022 15:28:52` ,  how do I make even `new Date()` to output the same  data in my nodejs script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Date(dateString) and new Date(dateString)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505693/difference-between-datedatestring-and-new-datedatestring)

Comment: And printing the ISO UTC representation of a date object, when you do console log is just the default behaviour of the Node REPL ...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is pretty well described on this topic : [How to initialize a JavaScript Date to a particular time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone)

To summarize, you only have to do `today.toLocaleString('IN', { timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' })` to get the time in India.
Please note that I'm not sure I picked the good timezone, so you might need to adjust that.

Comment: The problem is not the timezone, the problem is 1) two different initializations of a Date which return different things (one returns a `string`, the other returns a `Date` object) and 2) the default behaviour of the node REPL (which defaults to `adateobject.toISOString()`  on `console.log(adateobject)`

Comment: Since the title of your post is 'set timezone in nodejs' and in your example the two times are not the same, I think this is misleading. Anyway if the issue is the output format, you can do `today.toString()` which will output the same data as when you use Date()